# Trim from String after decimal places to 18 places in java - roundoff not required)

Tags: java, substring

I am working on a legacy code where i have String field which hold some amount value, which should have only 18 char after decimal place, not more than that.

I have achieved this like below -

```
        String str = "0.0040000000000000001";
    String[] values = StringUtils.split(str,".");
    System.out.println(str);
    String output = values[1];
    if(output.length()>18){
        output = output.substring(0,18);
    }
    System.out.println(values[0]+"."+output); // 0.004000000000000000
```

Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex for a one line solution:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\..{18}).*", "");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/djzegW).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex replacement here:

```java
String str = "0.0040000000000000001";
String output = str.replaceAll("(\\d+\\.\\d{18})(\\d+)", "$1");
System.out.println(output); // 0.004000000000000000
```

Comment: I think you’re going to have problems with `double` when there is more than 1 digit before the decimal point. OP says nothing about a limit on the number of digits before the dot.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a method, and test several alternatives to see which is better. You will have to first define what "better" means for your specific use-case: less memory? faster?

I propose:

```
public static String trimDecimalPlaces(String input, int places) {
    int dotPosition = input.indexOf(".");
    int targetSize = dotPosition + places + 1;
    if (dotPosition == -1 || targetSize > input.length()) {
        return input;
    } else {
        return input.substring(0, targetSize);
    }
}
```

This has a speed advantage over regex-based solutions, but it is certainly longer in terms of code.

Comment: “Performance” at this level is almost never required; the difference between regex and substring would be a few microseconds. Plus regex has the advantage of working when there is no dot in the String and when there are less than 18 digits, all in one simple line of bug free code.

Comment: It *is* however better than OP's approach of using split and throwing when no dot exists (the above code is free from that problem) - an I would argue that regexes that are not understood are hardly "simple".